# Which is best Search to install on Desktop windows 2008 computer

Tags: search, windows-server-2008

I Liked Google desktop search but i don't like the text based interface.

Is there any other search which good graphical interface for windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I recall correctly, Google desktop search just indexes the files for you for fast searching later. You can [install the Windows Indexing Service](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/954822) on Server 2008 which works similarly, and allows you to add or exclude certain file types in the index as well. This is the same service which comes installed on the desktop-based versions of Windows.

Comment: i will try that

Comment: I dont like the building windows search as the indexing services takes up too many ressources.

Comment: @Ber depends on the horsepower of your machine.

Comment: Well, terrabyte HD, 3.0 Ghz, 8 GB RAM, I still find the build in search to be crap. Its indexing in the background when I need my CPU for other purposes. Basically I just was it to index when I need to search or it should index when I add new files - automatically. Not as a delayed background process. I would also like to get ride of "context" search as I dont need it. An option for this would be nicere.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could have a look at Copernic (www.copernic.com). I have used it on for a few years on m office laptop when Outlook had pathetical search features and Google hadn't "invaded" the desktop yet.

Answer (score 0):

You should try [Everything](http://everything.com)
It's a super fast windows search, nice and clean :)

Comment: Although it's really fast and slim, Everything only searches in filenames, not in the content!

Comment: OK ! But I see that author doesn't mention about contents :)